# Text editor SQL Microsoft Management Studio 2012

Tags: ssms

I've created and succesfully compiled new procedure in SQL Microsoft Management Studio 2012.

After that I want to use it in other procedure like exec my_new_procedure.

It works perfect and procedure compiled as well, but in editor of Microsoft Management Studio 2012 my procedure call (exec my_new_procedure) underlined with red line as called procedure is not exists.

Situation is fixed after I close and run again Microsoft Management Studio.
How can fix it without reload Microsoft Management Studio?

Comment: Right click the database `programmability` and do referesh

Comment: Thanks, but seems it doesn't work :-(
I've done refresh as you suggested and opened again my procedure. The call of my new procedure is still underlined with red.

Comment: Try this `Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

once you create a new SQL Server object, your newly created object does not get updated in the IntelliSence Local Cache and due to this, it shows red line underneath that object. So you just need to refresh SSMS IntelliSence Local Cache and once you refresh it, `IntelliSence` will automatically add newly created object in the cache and the red line will disappear. try this

```
Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache
```

[image]

or simply do

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>